# Plotting different lines with the points saved in a file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file as below:

```
0.0120363241833/ 200497.697562   
0.0152237370833/    200496.992937    
0.0181834776333/    200496.122072    
0.0211432181833/    200495.303516    
0.0241029587333/    200494.602714    
0.0270626992833/    200493.73507     
0.0300224398333/    200493.033097    
0.0332098527333/    200492.167099    
0.0361695932833/    200491.352509    
0.0391293338333/    200490.603494    
0.0420890743833/    200489.842834    
0.0450488149333/    200489.147658
```

So I want to read each two successive points and draw the line passing through them.
What I did is:

```
do for [i=1:12]{

  t_0= awk 'NR==i {print $1}' "../graph1.txt"

  t_1= awk 'NR==$1+i {print $1}' "../graph1.txt"

  p_0= awk 'NR==i {print $2}' "../graph1.txt"

  p_1= awk 'NR==i+1 {print $2}' "../graph1.txt"


  m= (p_1-p_0)/(t_0-t_1)

  f(x) = m*(x-t_0)+p_0

  plot f(x)

}
```

But it does not work, can anyone give me suggestion to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a loop here. You can use `awk` to split your data into pairs of points and use `with lines`, like this:

```
plot '<awk -F/ ''NR%2{print ""}{print $1,$2}'' ../graph1.txt' with lines
```

The `-F` switch to awk specifies the input field delimeter (a forward slash). The first `awk` block prints a blank line every two lines. The second prints the two columns, separated by the default output field separator (which is a single space).

You can also change the datafile separator in gnuplot, thereby shortening the awk script:

```
set datafile separator '/'
plot '<awk ''NR%2{print ""}1'' ../graph1.txt' with lines
```

Here, the `1` at the end of the awk command tells awk to perform the default action, which is to print the whole line.

Either way, here's what you get:

[image: output of plot command]

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the `/` and add a blank line every two lines:

```
0.0120363241833 200497.697562
0.0152237370833 200496.992937

0.0181834776333 200496.122072
0.0211432181833 200495.303516

0.0241029587333 200494.602714
0.0270626992833 200493.73507

...
```

Then a simple

```
plot 'data.dat' w l
```

will do what you want.